# I am trying to setup the local 0x-api. (https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api). However I am encountering an error which doesn’t look handled?

Tags: 0x

[image: Image showing the error encountered when 0x-api is tried to run locally]

When tried to run a local version 0x-api, an internal server error is encountered. How do we overcome this to complete the local setup?

Error Message

```
{"level":"info","time":1634684466948,"pid":221370,"hostname":"aishu","req":{"id":"3dbbba61-dd55-4c03-a77c-7be5564e0b3a","method":"POST","url":"/orderbook/v1/order","query":{},"params":{},"headers":{"content-type":"application/json","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.8","accept":"*/*","postman-token":"6d4888c5-f59e-4c1f-b5cc-6f3d6b9dc2ec","host":"localhost:3001","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"910"},"remoteAddress":"::1","remotePort":38608,"body":{"makerToken":"0x39b8f771b76c59f1124dc4d4c9752799d3def99f","takerToken":"0x03a4132297a6956aadc3149214e79c2d98e8ad32","makerAmount":"10000","takerAmount":"20000","maker":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","taker":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","chainId":3,"verifyingContract":"0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff","takerTokenFeeAmount":"0","sender":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","feeRecipient":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","pool":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","salt":"846314","expiry":"0","signature":{"v":28,"r":"0xbc4bfc5fb14fcc580ce77055428c85bfe2fb9948682f327b0f88b335a97acfca","s":"0x73770af95619f7304cf0e6236e3bbb7236b26d4bee9d8e2e2b197376a139a35b","signatureType":3}}},"res":{"statusCode":500,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"53","etag":"W/\"35-q3ds3O+xttVHYK6psNZOcwB1doM\""},"statusMessage":"Internal Server Error"},"err":{"type":"Error","message":"failed with status code 500","stack":"Error: failed with status code 500\n    at ServerResponse.onResFinished (/home/akshay/Desktop/dextf/0x-api/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:73:38)\n    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:326:22)\n    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:735:10)\n    at onCorkedFinish (_stream_writable.js:673:5)\n    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:490:5)\n    at afterWriteTick (_stream_writable.js:477:10)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)"},"responseTime":18,"msg":"request errored"}
```

Comment: What value have you set for `ETHEREUM_RPC_URL`? 500 errors can be due to network timeouts from RPC providers.

Comment: I have used the Infura RPC. 
And I can confirm that the infura RPC end point is working. I have checked it in other application.

Comment: Can you include the error message as text?

Comment: I have added the error json in the body. Please check

Answer (score 0):

I checked back with the team and we are in the process of fixing the handling of this error: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/pull/774/files. Thanks for reporting!